# Spacetime background of Quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spacetime, schroedinger-equation, metric-tensor

Why is it said that the Schrodinger equation suggests a fixed, non-dynamical background spacetime, with time as an external parameter? How does this interpretation come about from the Schrodinger equation?

I guess what I am asking in general is, how does one go about to infer anything about the spacetime background QM is formulated upon?

Comment: Who is this "we" you speak of? At face value, I'd say that this "interpretation" comes just from observing that there is no quantity in the Schrödinger equation that would allow time or space to be *dynamical*. There's only the Hamiltonian and the wavefunction.

Comment: Yes, and the wavefunction belongs in the Hilbert space. So my question is, how does this give us any information on the spacetime background? (Please see the edit)

Comment: The Schroedinger equation doesn't suggest anything about spacetime. It's a quantum mechanical toy model that works for certain classes of non-relativistic systems, while spacetime is relativistic by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spacetime geometry may be indirectly read from the differential operators in the equations controlling other objects – particles and (matter) fields. Schrödinger's equation contains the differential operator 
$$\Delta = \nabla^2 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}  $$
which is the operator of the general form 
$$\sum_{ij} g^{ij} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$$
with $g^{ij}=\delta^{ij}$ i.e. $1$ for $i=j$ and $0$ for $i\neq j$.

This special form of the metric tensor (the coefficients $g^{ij}$) is known as the geometry of the flat 3-dimensional space. Because the usual Schrödinger's equation never contains any difficult coefficients in front of the second spatial derivatives, it *means* that the wave function "propagates" in the flat 3-dimensional space.

Because the flat 3-dimensional space has a geometry that isn't affected by the objects, matter, and fields that are present in the geometry – indeed, it's completely constant as a function of time $t$ here – we say that it is "non-dynamical". The word "dynamical" means "dependent on time", actually just "dependent on time through the dependence on other objects".

Similarly, there is no time-dependent coefficient in Schrödinger's equation in front of the time derivative $\partial / \partial t$, so the time is non-dynamical as well.

To make spacetime dynamical means to introduce new fields $g_{\mu\nu}(x,y,z,t)$ – either classical fields or quantum fields (or something that is effectively equivalent) – whose dependence on $x,y,z,t$ is affected by the matter around; and to use this $g^{\mu\nu}$ as coefficients in front of all differential operators, and other terms, that appear in the equations for fields and wave functions etc.

When we introduce this dynamical $g_{\mu\nu}$, the spacetime becomes curved in general, and the curvature depends on the matter and energy distributed in the space. This curvature will manifest itself as the gravitational force. That's how Einstein's general theory of relativity explains the gravitational force – it's due to the curved space.

Comment: I can understand how you read off the diagonal space components of the Minkowski metric from the differential operators, but what about the partial time derivative on the RHS? I am probably missing something here, but it's not a second order derivative, so you can't possibly read off g^{00} from it. And even if you could somehow, the component turns out to be -1, and the metric is (-1,-1,-1,-1) - definitely not Minkowski metric.

Comment: @Razor: see [Relativistic Quantum Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Relativistic_quantum_mechanics) where you can directly read off the Minkowski metric.  The [ordinary time dependent Schroedinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Time-dependent_equation) has an extra imaginary factor for the temporal part.

Comment: @Razor, in non-relativistic physics (or geometry), time is separated from space and 1-dimensional geometry doesn't need a 2-index tensor - you may just take $\sqrt{g_{tt}}$ and get the "einbein" which may be substituted in terms of first derivatives, too. The Galileo symmetry - a contraction of the Poincaré-Lorentz group - is less simple and constrained. But the general logic still works. Alternatively, you may show that the non-rel. Schr. equation is a limit of a relativistic equation where you may extract the full 4D metric tensor, and it will also be flat and non-dynamical 4D spacetime.